# How to solve CERT_UNTRUSTED error in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, nodemailer

I am trying to send an email with nodemailer. I already managed to send it from another host but now I want to send emails from another address. These are the versions of nodemailer I am using (from my `package.json`):

```
"nodemailer": "1.3.4",
"nodemailer-smtp-transport": "1.0.2",
```

This is the information I have about my webmail:

[image: RoundCube Mail Client Configuration]

I set up nodemailer like this:

```
    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: 'securemail.linevast.de',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'website@dynamic-objects.de', // this is my login name
            pass: 'mypassword'
        },
        maxConnections: 5,
        maxMessages: 10
    }));
```

And when I try to send an email I get the following error message.

`[Error: certificate not trusted] code: 'CERT_UNTRUSTED'`

The [website](https://webmail.linevast.de/) is verified by **GeoTrust Inc** so I believe it is quite trustworthy. Is there a way to make nodemailer trust the certificate or force it to send the email even though it does not trust it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you sure that you have the same cert instaled in the mail server and the web sever? Looks like no...  your mail server is using the default unsigned certificate.

Comment: I didn't install set up those servers, just saw in my browser that the web server has a GeoTrust certificate. The costumer service said that `securemail.linevast.de` uses a trusted certificate. Is there a way to make nodemailer ignore this warning?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can tell nodemailer to not check the certificate trust.

This is the option:

```
tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
```

use it on the initial transport object:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport('SMTP',{
        host: 'mail.mailserver.com',
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: 'user@mailserver.com',
            pass: 'passwd'
        },            
        authMethod:'NTLM',
        secure:false,
        // here it goes
        tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
        debug:true
    })
);
```

Comment: Anyways, since you have a good payed certificate available, try to get it on the mail server instaled since its more secure( not the cert itself but right now you are trusting any certificate).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now it works. I will still try to figure the issue about the certificate but this is a working temporary solution :)

Comment: Does option `secure` need to be true? Doesn't make sense to me having tls with `secure:false`

Comment: @Timo, check http://nodemailer.com/smtp/#tls-options, there you can see that "secure" is not related to this answer, i got the code from one of my apps that needed it to be false.

Comment: I was getting 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'. This also fixed my problem!